# bytearray encoding, data misrepresented

Tags: python, python-bytearray

I have a bytearray as follows:

```
frame = bytearray()
frame.append(0x6)
frame.append(0x8)
frame.append(0xf1)
frame.append(0x1b)
frame.append(0x3)
frame.append(0x2)
frame.append(0x1)
frame.append(0x0)
frame.append(0x0)
frame.append(0x0)
```

I am applying a CRC on all the bytes of the frame:

```
seed = 0xB7D2
POLY = 0x8408


class CanCRC:
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.value = value

    def update(self, char: bytes, crcres):
        for b in range(8):
            if ((crcres & 0x0001) ^ (char & 0x0001) == 0x0001):
                crcres = crcres >> 1
                crcres ^= POLY
            else:
                crcres = crcres >> 1
            char = char >> 1
        return crcres

can = CanCRC(value=seed)
for i in range(0, len(frame)):
    can.value = can.update(frame[i], can.value)


frame.extend((can.value).to_bytes(2, byteorder='little'))

print(hex(can.value))
print(frame)
```

The final CRC value is 0xcc30, but when added to the bytearray, the array is showing:

```
bytearray(b'\x06\x08\xf1\x1b\x03\x02\x01\x00\x00\x000\xcc')
```

Why would this be? I'm getting `\x000\xcc` instead of `\x30\xcc`

I've noticed this happen with other bytes in an array too.. it's not encoding properly or something...

Any help appreciated

Comment: Do you know what is the ASCII code for the character `'0'`? It is 48 or 0x30 in hexadecimal. So `b'0'` and `b'\30'` represent exactly the same byte string containing a single `0` character: the arrays shows what you want.

Comment: Start a Python REPL session and type `b'\x30'` and see what happens.